# Code design: Observer pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, client

I am developing the **client-server-architecture** of a game. The "Client" class  communicates with the server and has to **interact with other classes depending on the type of information it receives**, for instance: If the client class receives

- map data then it should interact with the class which stores the maps
- data about other players (name, ip, ...) then it should interact with the GUI (in order to display the data)

Of course, the client class could just store references (pointer) to all the classes it has to communicate with. I'm looking for a way to solve this problem more beautifully. Would you use the **Observer** pattern and just **notify** the observers when the client receives a message?

Comment: Your client sounds like an observer (in the view) since it receives information. Your question isn't clear. What do you mean by "solve this problem more beautifully"? Design patterns are not about making code more beautiful (although that often is the result); they're about solving a problem. What is the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using the Observer pattern after I had a look at the explanation found here: [Link](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/observer.html)